# Absolute element inside fixed element does obey z-index

Tags: html, css, css-position, z-index

I have an `absolute` element inside of a `fixed` element.  When another element further in the DOM is `absolute` with a negative margin to (sometimes) cover the above element, `z-index` does not have any effect: https://jsfiddle.net/esqg4aw2/42/

I thought z-index was supposed to override everything?

I know I could make them sibling elements to get around this, but this is being used as a drop-menu, so there needs to be a parent-child arrangement to inherit `:hover`

Comment: you cannot, position:fixed create a stacking context so that element need to have a higher z-index. z-index of its child are irrelevant when it comes to *outside* elements

Comment: @TemaniAfif
OK, thanks.  I guess I'll have to work around it by placing them as siblings.